# Change plot label when plotting different dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I aggregated on pivot tables some time series information, so each pivot table have columns labeled 2015, 2014, etc. I want to compare each pivot table, so I'm plotting them on the same axis:

```
print pv_test_A.columns
Int64Index([2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015], dtype='int64')

print pv_test_B.columns
Int64Index([2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015], dtype='int64')

fig, axes = plt.subplots()
pv_test_A.loc[:,[2015]].plot(ax=axes)
pv_test_B.loc[:,[2015]].plot(ax=axes)
```

in this case, each line will have the same label on the graph, 2015. I tried passing the `label` argument to the plot to no effect. Is there a way to rename the labels without having to resort to using plt.legend or annotate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`.rename()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html):

```
pv_test_A.loc[:,[2015]].rename(columns={2015: "New Label A"}).plot(ax=axes)
pv_test_B.loc[:,[2015]].rename(columns={2015: "New Label B"}).plot(ax=axes)
```

The underlying data is preserved, but the columns to be plotted are given a different label for plotting purposes.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
score["vifp_me_gt"].plot.hist(alpha=0.4, label="a")
score["vifp_ori_gt"].plot.hist(alpha=0.4, label="b")
plt.xlabel("Score")
plt.title("Frequency Score Visual Information Fidelity (vif-p)")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: My dataframe]
[image: After change plot label]